# twisted python garbage collection

Tags: python, garbage-collection, twisted

I currently am developing a python twisted server to use as a message processing application.  I have come across an odd problem.

I specify my class to handle the get_POST to the server, and pass the received message to a class which further processes it.

The message processes into a dictionary that is a member of an object that gets instantiated every time there is a new message.  However, after (for example) a message contained 10 items for the dictionary, when a message with only 9 entries is processed, the 10th will still be in the dictionary.

I've been able to work around this by explicitly clearing out the dictionary before processing the message e.g.:

d = {}

However, I'm puzzled because the object should have been out of scope and garbage collected after the dictionary was further processed, and reinstantiated on every new message.  It seems to be acting like the object is not an instance and preserving members as if it were a singleton, or the members were static.

Do the normal scoping policies act the same when under the twisted framework, or do I need to do something additional to ensure that objects are GC'd when they fall out of scope?

Thanks!

-joe.

Comment: This would have been a very easy question if you'd included a little bit of code illuminating your approach (particularly if it actually were an http://sscce.org/).  With that information omitted, this is a "guess what's wrong with the invisible program" question. :(

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul, we were able to figure this out down below, and it had to do with my misunderstanding of class and instance scoped variables, and nothing to do with twisted.

Answer (score 2):

How are you initializing the class containing the dictionary?  I would think if you used something along the lines of:

```
class YourClass(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.d = {}
```

That it would solve your problem.  Unless it's some sort of object which is not instantiated on every message but instead pooled and reused by the Twisted framework.  Have you tried adding some sort of log output to the `__init__` method of your class to see if it is in fact being instantiated per message?

Comment: yeh, its being instantiated, and i've been neurotic about logging so i was able to rule out other modules being called.  basically i ended up doing what you suggested and put in ClassName.d = {} inside the __init__.  But, it still bothers me that the instance of the object is not being GCd when it should be falling out of scope.  Thanks.

Comment: That's your problem, Classname.var creates a class variable, putting self.var inside `__init__` creates an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your class definition looked something like this:

```
class MyCoolMessage(object):
    d={}
    def addMessage(self,incoming_msg):
        d['a']=incoming_msg[0]
        d['b']=incoming_msg[1]
        d['c']=incoming_msg[2]
```

this is different than what @John Gaines Jr. pointed out above and his approach is the correct one. You should initialize per insatnce variables in the **init** rather than on class level.

The problem with

```
class MyCoolMessage(object):
    d={}
```

setup is that scope of d becomes the Class rather than the insatnce, it should be even accesible without initiation of class through

```
print (MyCoolMessage.d)
```